# html code inside javascript function divxwebplayer

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have one website that contains database of movies (like IMDB). I would like when user click on movie cover (image) a window of divxwebplayer to open and play avi file from server. I have try but no success.

inside img tag a i have added onclick function that calls showmyvideo(). then i write function showmyvideo() { } but i don't know how to write html code inside javascript function to be executed. here is my html code that needs to be executed inside showmyvideo() function:

```
 <object classid="clsid:67DABFBF-D0AB-41fa-9C46-CC0F21721616" width="320" height="260" codebase="http://go.divx.com/plugin/DivXBrowserPlugin.cab">
<param name="custommode" value="none" />
<param name="autoPlay" value="false" />
<param name="src" value="film.avi" />

<embed type="video/divx" src="<?php echo $moviename ?>.avi" custommode="none" width="320" height="260" autoPlay="false"  pluginspage="http://go.divx.com/plugin/download/"></embed>
```

Many Thanks.

i wouldlike when user click on image that divxweb player is openede on the screen and play avi file.

this is code that i im trying and traying but no go.please if some one can help me.

```
<!-- DivX Web Player -->
<a onClick="DivXWebPlayer('<?php echo $title; ?>', '<?php echo $year; ?>')" class="item-image">

function DivXWebPlayer(title, year)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://<?php echo $source; ?>/player.php?title='+title+'&year='+year,
        success: function(data) {
        $('#popup2').html('<div>' + data + '</div>');
        },
        error: function(request, error, errormessage) {
        $("#messages").html(error + '\n' + errormessage);
      }
    });
    e.preventdefault();
    return false;
};
```

and a file player.php

```
<?php
/* get movie location */
$tit = $_GET['title'];
$yer = $_GET['year'];
$gen = $_GET['genre'];
```

?>

```
<div>
<object classid="clsid:67DABFBF-D0AB-41fa-9C46-CC0F21721616" width="320" height="260" codebase="http://go.divx.com/plugin/DivXBrowserPlugin.cab">
    <param name="src" value="movie.divx"/>

    <embed
        type="video/divx"
        src="./Drama/<?php echo $tit; ?> [<?php echo $yer; ?>].avi"
        width="320" height="260"
        pluginspage="http://go.divx.com/plugin/download/">
    </embed>
</object>
</div>
```

any help welcome..where i was doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use innerHTML.

Declare a element somewhere in your web page and keep the an id for ex, "demo". Something like:

`<div id="demo">
</div>`

Then, in the javascript function, do this:

`function showmyvideo()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="yourhtmlcode";
}`

Comment: nobody knows?i would like to know where to start fixing issues...but after lot trial and errors i im unable to run divx web player onthe center of screen and playing avi file when user click on a href link.

Comment: ok..i fixed problem and now is all working...except that divx web player 2.0 does not support ftp protocol only http. so i installed divx web player 1.5 and now is ftp protocol for streaming working...execept that picture is not sharp and smooth...can anyone reccomanded me i good avi player that i can embded html code to web page and picture is rooning smooth and sharp? i tried vlc player but buffering over ftp is not working property.